# BadWindow crash in tkinter after calling glfw.init()

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, x11, glfw

I have the following code, which works on Windows, but crashes on Linux with X11:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""Tkinter crashes on X11 when popup windows
are closed after calling glfw.init()
"""

from sys import exit

from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

from glfw import init


class MainWindow(Tk):
    """Main window."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if not init():
            exit(2)

        showinfo('Close me', 'I dare you')


def main():
    """Run the script."""

    MainWindow().mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

After clicking *OK* in the message box on Linux/X11, the program crashes with:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  15 (X_QueryTree)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x4c0000a
  Serial number of failed request:  778
  Current serial number in output stream:  778
```

The addresses vary after each run, but the overall error stays the same.
I was able to reduce the problem to the call of `glfw.init()` which results in subsequent closing of tkinter Windows to crash the program. However, this does not happen on Windows systems.

Some system info:

```
$ uname -r
5.16.16-arch1-1
$ pacman -Q xorg-server
xorg-server 21.1.3-6
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
$ pacman -Q glfw python-glfw
glfw-x11 3.3.6-1
python-glfw 2.1.0-2
```

Why is this program crashing on my system?
What can I do to make it run just like on windows?

Comment: Totally reproduces. Shouldn't this be an issue in pyGLFW? https://github.com/FlorianRhiem/pyGLFW/issues I mean I'm not sure there's anything to be answered to your question.

Comment: Your code is reproducible on my Ubuntu 20.04. However, when I commented out all the `tkinter` code, and did just this: `if not init(): exit(2)`, the code worked without any error messages. So there's something about `glfw` and `tkinter` being in the same program that causes this. This is not entirely unexpected, as running multiple different UI modules in the same script is known to cause problems.

Comment: Well, I need glfw for some voronoi calculation with OpenGL and tkinter for the GUI. And since it works on Windows, it should also work on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert on this, but if you only want to have working code you have to call `glfw.init()` before `super().__init__()` like this:

```py
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

from glfw import init


class MainWindow(Tk):
    """Main window."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not init():
            exit(2)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        showinfo('Close me', 'I dare you')


def main():
    """Run the script."""
    MainWindow().mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I think it is better to put the `glfw.init()` in `main` before `MainWindow().mainloop()`, but i wanted to make clear that i think the problem is directly in `super().__ini__()`.

I did not tested any function of glfw, i only checked this because of [other questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53396796/python-crash-when-trying-to-use-tk-tk-after-creating-opengl-window-on-macos-mo)

Here are some links you can check, maybe they can help:
[togl](http://togl.sourceforge.net/index.html)
[code project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1073475/OpenGL-in-Python-with-TKinter)

Comment: This is a good hint. But it only moves the issue, since a subsequent call to `glfw.create_window` will cause the same issue. And I cannot move that call before the main window's init since it's called on every window resizing.

Comment: I added 2 links you can check, maybe they help